# Грамматическая основа предложения

Tags: синтаксис

*Идешь по лесной тропинке и вдруг услышишь резкий цокающий звук*. Это играют на деревьях белки. Где во втором предложении основа? На первый взгляд, белки играют. А местоимение это тогда что такое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В школьной грамматике ЧАСТИЦА для указания на мысль, кот. содержится в предшествующем предложении, а вообще указательное объектное местоимение-объект объяснения, не являющийся отдельным членом предложения, оно относится ко всему предложению в целом.

Comment: Вероятно, это обстоятельственный детерминант - указывает на обстоятельства всей ситуации (или ситуант)

Comment: А если просто - это белки. Тогда это становится подлежащим?

Comment: Да, тогда ЭТО- подлежащее

Comment: А разница в чем?

Comment: Разница выявляется при определении грамматической основы.Это играют на деревьях белки. кто?-белки.Что делают? Играют. Кто?-Это Это есть что? Это есть белки.

Answer (score 2):

"Это" употребляется как указательное слово на границе двух предложений, из которых второе содержит в себе истолкование, разъяснение первого.
"Идешь по лесной тропинке и вдруг услышишь резкий цокающий звук". Это  белки.  Думаю, здесь указательное слово перед назывным предложением (состоит только из подлежащего). Для сравнения: Это что? Это белки. Здесь ЭТО - подлежащее.

ОТВЕТ 2.
 Это что за шум? Это белки (шумят). Они прыгают с ветки на ветку.

Можно считать предложение неполным, но в любом случае "шум не может быть белками. Грамматическая роль слова ЭТО не изменилась, оно по-прежнему является указательным 
словом.

ОТВЕТ 3. Я уже в предыдущем ответе изменила вид предложения: не назывное, а неполное. А теперь думаю, что оно не назывное, не неполное, а просто неправильное. Так нельзя продолжить заданный текст"Идешь по лесной тропинке и вдруг услышишь резкий цокающий звук".

Comment: Вот это замудрили, куда там нулевому окончанию до грамматической основы.

Comment: >Вот это замудрили,   
  
Да нет, как раз все понятно. Верно или нет - вопрос обсуждаемый. Но мысль вполне понятна.  

Я, кстати, нечто подобное хотел сам написать, ну, может, другими словами... Побоялся нарушить зыбкий мир...

Действительно, в рамках существующих описаний грамматики "Это белки" позволяет быть разобрано двумя способами. Выбор варианта определяется контекстом. Первый же вариант "это белки играют" не предполагает подобной свободы выбора.

Comment: Да я не о себе, я сразу про школьников думаю. Вы считаете, это легче понять, чем про нулевое окончание?

Comment: А, не... Я про школьников вообще не думаю. Не царское это дело. 

Сами мы не местные, нам бы, убогим, самим разобраться.

Comment: София,ЭТО не может быть указательным словом в назывном предложении,в указательных назывных есть только указательные частицы вот, вот и, вон, вон и: Вот место, где их дом стоит; Вот ива (А. Пушкин); Вот и мостик/ (Н. Гоголь). http://www.lingvotech.com/nazivnie_predlozheniya Назывные (номинативные) предложения — это односоставные предложения, в которых утверждается существование, бытие предметов или явлений, а это предложение(это белки)утверждает не  существование белок, а то, что слышимые звуки издают белки. (звуки = это)